# Is it possible to extract items from any dropdownlist box?

Tags: web-development, asp.net

> Hi, I've one dropdown list box for "City" and another one for
>   corresponding localities. Localities list is placed in a javascript
>   file. As i select any city from "City" dropdown list box, then
>   corresponding localities are displayed in "Locality" dropdownlist box.
>   I want to extract the list of Localities from "Locality" dropdownlist
>   box. Is it possible ?

Comment: You probably want to post this on SO

Comment: I just need solution whether on SO or SU.

Comment: If you are populating the dropdown from js then why do you need to extract it?

Comment: Hi Paul, This is not my website. i just want to extract list of localities from the dropdownlist box. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You might first try opening the page source and seeing if what you are looking for is there.  In Firefox for example right click and select page source.

Failing that you could fiddle with the javascript to have it output to the page rather than the drop down.  A bit messy, but might work.

Comment: Hi Eliptical, Thanks for your efforts for me. I tried what u asked me to do. First i go through "View Page Source". But couldn't succeeded bcz locality list is coming from js file. Second thing that (locality) js file is not accessible that's why can't fiddle.

Comment: Can you post the URL?

Comment: What you are looking is not being generated by the javascript.  Look at the html source (as I described in my answer above).  All of what you are looking for is there I think.  Here is an example of what I cut out of it to show you, "<option class="heading-dd" value="4320">Mumbai</option>
<option value="4320-1001041">Mumbai - Central Mumbai</option>
<option value="4320-1001042">Mumbai - South Mumbai</option>
<option value="4320-1001043">Mumbai - Western Suburbs</option>
<option value="4320-1001044">Mumbai - Harbour Line</option>
<option value="4320-1001045">Mumbai - Central Line</option>...
"

Comment: You are talking about Cities dropdownlist box whereas i am talking about "Locality" dropdownlist box. Pls have a look at "Locality" dropdownlist box. you'll find that these are coming from js file.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry.  You're right.  So you will have to track the JavaScript back and see how to modify it.  Looks like a good challenge.  It you bear donw on it it won't take you too long.